# uWSGI vs Twisted Matrix

Tags: python, uwsgi, twisted

[uWSGI](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/) can be configured in [ashyncronous mode](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Async.html) same as Twisted Matrix, but has anyone tried to compare these to servers in terms of performance? If we need to develop a Python web app handling thousands of connections concurrently, which one of these servers would be the best choice? If someone has implemented a high-traffic web app using any of this servers could please share his thoughts? 
Thanks

Comment: Note that this question is not (or should not be) a question about comparing uWSGI to Twisted's WSGI support.  Twisted's WSGI support is actual WSGI support - which means that it is not asynchronous.  Thus it doesn't make sense to compare the runtime performance of these two things.  Instead, it makes more sense to compare uWSGI with Twisted's native, asynchronous web server APIs (which are not at all WSGI compatible).

Comment: For anybody looking for an answer to this, there's a beautiful benchmark demonstration over at - http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers